# Power Query Table.Group List.Sum(two columns)

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

Trying to figure out how to perform the sum of two columns inside a Table.Group step.

This one throws:

> Expression.Error: We cannot convert Type to List type.

M Code:

```
= Table.Group(PreviousStep, {"PF"}, {{"ColumnName", each List.Sum({[Column1], [Column2]})}, type number})
```

M Gurus: Is this even possible?

Objective: Simplify steps (actually I have 12 columns I want to reduce to 6 - adding pairs, grouping them, all in one simple step)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can kind of do it if you create a custom column to sum within that step. Something like this:

```
= Table.Group(
      PreviousStep,
      {"PF"},
      {{"ColumnName",
        each List.Sum(
                 Table.AddColumn(
                     _,
                     "Custom", each [Column1] + [Column2]
                 )[Custom]
             ),
        type number
      }}
 )
```

Comment: Thank you! just optimized it to use List.Sum({[Column1],[Column2]} instead of "+" operator to deal with null values.

Comment: Also, the second "PreviousStep" should be "_"